# How to change a variable once an operation is performed in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to delete a file if it does not match another file. Once I delete the file I want to change a variable from "1" to "0" in order to do another process. However, when I try to change it using `vars` and run it. Instead of it deleting the old file and installing the new one, it just skips both.

**Code:**

```
# Runs if the file on the target host don't match another remote host file
   - name: Remove old tar file
      file:
         path: /tmp/{{ target_tar_name }}
         state: absent
      vars:
         target_version_matched: "0"
      # Below should be hostname with tarfile on it
      when: 
        - target_version_matched == "1"
        - tar_version != target_tar_name


 # Copies the file from the host to the target machine if nothing exist    
    - name: Copy Remote-To-Remote (host to target)
      synchronize: src=/tmp/{{ tar_version }} dest=/tmp
      delegate_to: 10.x.x.x
      when: target_version_matched == "0"
```

**Error:**

```
TASK [Remove old tar file] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [10.x.x.x]

TASK [Copy Remote-To-Remote (host to target)] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [10.x.x.x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
# Runs if the file on the target host don't match another remote host file
    - name: Remove old tar file
      file:
         path: /tmp/{{ target_tar_name }}
         state: absent
      # Below should be hostname with tarfile on it
      when: 
        - target_version_matched == "1"
        - tar_version != target_tar_name
      register: result

   - name: Check if result changes
     set_fact:
         target_version_matched: "0"
     when: result.changed

 # Copies the file from the host to the target machine if nothing exist    
    - name: Copy Remote-To-Remote (host to target)
      synchronize: src=/tmp/{{ tar_version }} dest=/tmp
      delegate_to: 10.x.x.x
      when: target_version_matched == "0"

      #when: result.changed # or you can use result directly here, if target_version_matched is not used anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation of the problem**

The task below will be always skipped because *vars* evaluates before *when*

```
   - name: Remove old tar file
      file:
         path: /tmp/{{ target_tar_name }}
         state: absent
      vars:
         target_version_matched: "0"
      when: 
        - target_version_matched == "1"
```

**Examples**

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    match: '999'
  tasks:

# Always skipped because 'match' is assigned '0' by 'vars' first
    - debug:
        var: match
      vars:
        match: '0'
      when: match == '1'
# TASK [debug] *********************************************
# skipping: [localhost]

# Always pass because 'match' is assigned '1' by 'vars' first
    - debug:
        var: match
      vars:
        match: '1'
      when: match == '1'
# TASK [debug] *********************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "match": "1"
# }

# Scope of variables declared inside a task is this task
    - debug:
        var: match
# TASK [debug] *********************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "match": "999"
# }

# All skipped because 'when' is applied to all tasks first
    - block:
        - debug:
            var: match
        - set_fact:
            match: '1'
        - debug:
            var: match
      when: match == '1'
# TASK [debug] *********************************************
# skipping: [localhost]
# TASK [set_fact] ******************************************
# skipping: [localhost]
# TASK [debug] *********************************************
# skipping: [localhost]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will make the needed adjustment